# android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

Open the new activity on my app that time i get a below error.

```
java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()
```

My xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/order_detail_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/appcolor"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

My java code:

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.order_detail);
    String orderid = getIntent().getStringExtra("order_detail_toolbar");

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("DDIT_Results");

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Any one know the solution please explain the error and give the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to get the Toolbar with wrong id.

you've set the id to be

`android:id="@+id/order_detail_toolbar"`

but are trying to get it on

`toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`

so change that line to `toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.order_detail_toolbar);`

Comment: Thanks id is mistake

Comment: If you're using an IDE like Android Studio a good tip is to CMD-click the id to see that it links to the correct element in your xml. It's a good way of navigating too, you can do the same on methods, classes etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.order_detail_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("DDIT_Results");
```

Comment: Thanx for your replay

Answer (score 1):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.order_detail_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);       
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("DDIT_Results");
```

Comment: This does not address the problem faced by the OP.